# Can ignore tag functionality to be improved to remove or collapse them off the screen?

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-watching, ignored-tags

I find sometimes when looking through several pages of results, or something that is cross-language similar, I get half a page of greyed-out answers, and half a page of not.

This would be best if it could weight the results by relevance and give all my **interesting tags** a **+5 relevance** and my **ignored tags** a **-5 relevance**. (thus boil my favorite tags to the top and flush my ignored tags to the bottom of the list.)

I feel like it would be a much better experience to get search results based on interest rather than the ***whole set of everything***.

Comment: Have you tried the "Hide ignored tags" option in your profile?

Comment: @mmyers♦: however, collapsing seems to be a nice option to me, too